# css underline for anchor without href

Tags: jquery, css

I have an `<a id="javascriptlink">` tag, without href. Its action handled by jquery onclick.
So, I want to put in css `a:link {text-decoration: underline;}` and `a:hover {text-decoration: none;}` to make it look like a link.

However, the anchor underline seems to only work when href attribute is presented. Any idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`a:link` works with the href being present only. If there isn't an href, it is only an anchor and not a link.

```
a {text-decoration: underline;}
```

Comment: +1 Simple. Somehow it never dawned on me that `a:link` is an anchor tag that is a link and `a` just applies to anchors in general. Makes complete sense. I have always used anchors as links and never simply anchors.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Just to add `a:link, a:visited {}` worked like a charm.

Comment: `cursor: pointer` is very important for mobile or the link may not work at all

Answer (score 9):

```
a{
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: cursor: pointer is especially important for iOS (not sure about Android)

Answer (score 8):

Just add the href attribute but make the link do nothing by canceling the event.

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); return false;" id="javascriptlink">
```

Comment: I think your attempt will stop all click activities

Comment: @thecodeparadox That is the intent, to make it behave like an un-linked anchor tag.